# How can resolve this error Template parsing error in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

[My controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uHPc.png)
[My repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcWXn.png)
[My Entity file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNeLN.png)
[My Html File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Oqa.png)
[Error while running 1/3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxwq0.png)
[Error page cont. 2/3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzSMy.png)
[Error page cont. 3/3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYtUx.png)

I am a beginner self learning through videos and courses, so please help me with it.

Comment: Please do not use [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question. Use the actual text of the code, data. errors instead. Use the appropriate [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for clarity.

Comment: You can also read [ask] and browse topics in the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Employee` entity is missing getters so you can't access the private fields. Thymeleaf calls the getters under the hood when you access `obj.field` ie it is translated into `obj.getField()`. Solution: add getters to your entity. Example for the name field:

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```